# How to add a new tab on a tab based application?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to design an iOS app, and was wondering how I could create a new tab/view for my application?

Or, if this is simpler to do, I have a view controller with a tab on it, how could I connect it to my main view controller?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? You can drag and drop a new tab onto the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

> Or, if this is simpler to do, I have a view controller with a tab on it, how could I connect it to my main view controller?

If you are in Storyboard, hold down the control key and drag with the mouse from the UITabBarController (the one without a view on it, just kinda a transparent grey background) to the UIViewController (has a solid white background color by default) you want to hook up.  Release the mouse click, and choose "view controllers" (under "Relationship Segue").  That will automatically add the tab bar to your new UIViewController and add a new icon in your UITabBarController.

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't want to start a new question for this, but how do you make a link so that when you press on it, it opens Safari?

Comment: That I'm not sure of.  I know there is a UIWebView that you drag-and-drop onto your viewcontroller (from the same place as where you get the labels, buttons, etc from) that will display websites, but I've never used it, so I'm not too familiar with it, other than knowing it exists.  That really is completely unrelated, so you should post a new question for it anyway.  Also, if my answer solved this question please "accept" it (green checkmark) and "upvote" it (arrow above the 0 on the left).